# Existence of an irreducible trinomial over finite fields?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Let $F_q$ be the finite field of $q$ elements. I am looking for the existence of an irreducible trinomial of the following form:
$$x^n-x^m-1$$
over $F_q$ for some $n,m.$
I think it should be true because we may choose $n$ big enough. 
In the case, $n$ is fixed, then the conjecture may be false. For example, at $n=2,q=5$, there is no such irreducible polynomial. What do you think?

Comment: $X^p-X-1$ works if $q = p^{f}$ and $f$ is not divisible by $p$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Schreier_theory

Comment: Thanks, I know that result also. I am looking for the answer for the case f is divisible by p as well. In this case, I believe the existence of irreducible polynomial of the form $x^n-x-1$ for n suitable (but not for all $n$: Calculations on Maple showed me that $n\neq 10$ if $p=3$). Besides, the polynomial $f(x)=x^p-x-1$ has exponent (order) $\frac{p^p-1}{p-1}$, Hence, we may construct some polynomials with bigger degree of the form $f(x^t)$ with suitable odd numbers $t$ by appling the following lemma:

Comment: LEMMA: $$f(x^t) \text{ is irreducible iff } \begin{array}{ll}1. gcd(t,\frac{p^p-1}{e})=1 \text{ and } \\2. p \text{ prime, } p\mid t \Rightarrow p\mid e \text{ and }\\ 3. 4 \mid t \Rightarrow 4 \mid (p^2-1)\end{array}
$$